# How do I print other parts of this json list in python?

Tags: python, json

First off I apologize if I use incorrect terms for any of this, I am just learning to use python and json.

I am trying to print the "name", "level", "class" and "experience" values out of this json code that I get from this code.

```
pathAPI = requests.get("http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Standard?limit=10")
data = json.loads(pathAPI.text)
print(data) 
for character in data['entries']:
    print('============================================================')
    print("Rank: ", character["rank"])
    print(character['character'])
```

the output I get looks like this

```
Rank:  1
{'name': 'PenDora', 'level': 100, 'class': 'Scion', 'id': 'cc248e0d23c849d71b40379d82dfc19b200bdb7b8ac63322f06de6483aaca5ea', 'experience': 4250334444}
```

but I would like for it to look like this

```
PenDora
100
Scion
4250334444
```

I have tried to add another for loop under the previous, but I get an error saying "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

```
pathAPI = requests.get("http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Standard?limit=10")

data = json.loads(pathAPI.text)
print(data) 
for character in data['entries']:
    print('============================================================')
    print("Rank: ", character["rank"])
    print(character['character'])    
    for playerInfo in character['character']:
        print(playerInfo['name'])
        print(playerInfo['level'])
        print(playerInfo['class'])
        print(playerInfo['experience'])
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you post a data sample of the data['entries'] dict. By the looks of things you are looping playerinfo over a single dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`character['character']` is dictionary, so you don't iterate over it with `for` loop, but access it directly with key.

For example:

```
import requests

data = requests.get("http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Standard?limit=10").json()

for character in data['entries']:
    print('============================================================')
    print("Rank: ", character["rank"])
    print(character['character']['name'])
    print(character['character']['level'])
    print(character['character']['class'])
    print(character['character']['experience'])
```

Prints:

```
============================================================
Rank:  1
PenDora
100
Scion
4250334444
============================================================
Rank:  2
TaylorSwiftVEVO
100
Scion
4250334444
============================================================

... and so on.
```